# PHP Sorting Inner, Inner Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Okay I have an array like this:

```
array {
    [0] => array {
               [0] => array {
                         ["Time"] => "01:00:00"
                      }
               [1] => array {
                         ["Time"] => "00:00:00"
                      }
    }
    [1] => array {
               [0] => array {
                         ["Time"] => "01:00:00"
                      }
               [1] => array {
                         ["Time"] => "00:00:00"
                      }
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is sort the inner inner array (the one with the time values) by the time values. Just so that inner array is sorted by the time values. How would I do this?

I do have PHP 5.3 installed if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function custom_map( $array ) {
    usort( $array, function( $a, $b ) {
        return strtotime($a['Time'])-strtotime($b['Time']) > 0;
    });
    return $array;
}

$new_array = array_map( "custom_map", $array );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: No that's sorting the outermost array. I just want to sort the arrays that contain the Time value. (The outer array order should be unaffected).

Comment: Sorry, I realized that and worked on an update but you beat me to it. Take a look at this.

Comment: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Yeah, as I updated the code I inadvertently removed ['Time'] at the end. Please try the updated code.

Comment: Okay that now leaves the first set of arrays in but removes the ones which contain the value Time and replaces them with NULL.

Comment: I'm sorry I did this way too fast. I forgot to return the value, I updated again.

Comment: And if mine doesn't work, do what xelber says because it's basically the same solution but uses foreach instead of array_map (which I think is a bit less elegant... on the other hand, sort might work and be more elegant than usort I now realize)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ( $array as $key => &$part )
{
    usort( &$part, function( $a, $b ) {
        return strtotime($a['Time'])-strtotime($b['Time']) > 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: The & before $part is deprecated, therefore I can't choose it as the final answer, thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(array(array("Time" => "01:00:00"), array("Time" => "02:00:00"), array("Time" => "00:00:00")),
             array(array("Time" => "02:00:00"), array("Time" => "01:00:00"), array("Time" => "00:00:00")));

$c = count($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    sort($arr[$i]);
}

var_dump($arr); // outputs desired array
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it gets any simpler to sort the second level -- iterate the first level and call `sort()` on each occurrence. Because your string are presumably `hh:ii:ss`, it is completely safe to compare them as simple strings (no need to `strtotime()`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/G5eab))

```
$array = [
    [
        ['Time' => "01:00:00"],
        ['Time' => "00:00:00"]
    ],
    [
        ['Time' => "01:00:00"],
        ['Time' => "00:00:00"]
    ]
];

array_walk($array, 'sort');
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Time' => '00:00:00',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Time' => '01:00:00',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Time' => '01:00:00',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Time' => '00:00:00',
    ),
  ),
)
```